# Dynamically Change API Environments Google Rollout Track

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, backend, google-play-console

I'm developing an Ionic(3 / 4)(Angular 4 - 7)-Cordova / Capacitor Cross Platform Application(s). I'm interested in switching API env based on the current rollout track in the Google Play Store. For example, once an application has been successfully tested and recommended to continue staging/production. I would like to have the API env dynamically changed (e.g., using a different URI domain to connect to REST API ) dependent on the Google Play Store Track.

I'm aware that I can use Google Developer Play Store API to identify / list versions and available tracks yet, I'm unaware if there's already an implementation or solution. I'm perfectly willing to design a solution though, I figure I find out if it's been done already rather than reinvent the wheel.

I'm hoping to implement a solution either to the REST API BACKEND or in the ionic framework layer rather than an integration at the native layer for scalability per-project. The purpose of doing this would enable CI rather than rebuilding the project and change the API URI domain for every environment. Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you find your answer?

Comment: Nope, not yet though I may just build something out

Comment: Kinda weird that this is not a norm. Are we missing something?

Comment: got tired of waiting, so I just created something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone's interested. The approach highlighted above is possible, couldn't get an answer so I just created something. Using Google Play Developer API. The process flow is as follows:
    [[image: Dynamic API Change Based on Google Rollout Track]]

For now it's a working prototype perhaps its not very efficient; I suppose it can be improved if the request was issued from a single server, or microservice. Though, I wanted to make the code recyclable and it's isolated from both the mobile application & Node Server.

If you are interested in learning more or would like to work on project. Please feel free to contact me.